# Getting 414 Request-URI Too Large while sending more then 250 waypoints to calculateroute.json

Tags: here-api

We are sending total 289 waypoints in Querystring.Getting error like 414 Request-URI Too Large in postman.Please help me to solve this issue.

***Code:***
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?&apiKey=*****&waypoint0 to waypoint280

Answer (score 0):

The server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This rare condition is only likely to occur when a client has improperly converted a POST request to a GET request with long query information, when the client has descended into a URI "black hole" of redirection (e.g., a redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of itself).

> We generally suggest less than 200 waypoints.

or probably this can answer your question-
[Maximum length of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)